# literature review research transgender youth of color

Tags: social-psychology, developmental-psychology, children, transgender, school

I'm currently working on a review of the literature. I'm looking for research on how community support can help trans youth of color. For instance, there is [research](https://www.mdpi.com/1660-4601/15/6/1289) that suggests that trans youth of color are more protected from social strains than white trans youth.

Is there more research on how forms of community support helps trans youth of color? Such as trans youth of color from more collectivist oriented cultures.